# completion and goto-function in matlab-mode

Tags: doom, cedet, matlab

I've been working with matlab-mode and matlab-shell for the last few days, and I'm really digging it so far.
The only two things I can't get to work properly are completion - neither in shell, nor in .m files - and jumping to function definitions, and I would really appreciate some help with these.
when I hit TAB in shell, my text turns into

```
>> emacsdocomplete('EEG.(cond')
```

and when I hit RETURN I get (the appropriate):

```
emacs_completions_output =
 java.lang.String[]:
   'cond'
   'condeig'
```

but it's not integrated into the shell properly, i.e. I can't choose which of the above I want, I have to re-type the command along with the chosen completion.
In .m files I just get nothing except for the word completion for words already in the buffer - which I've configured myself.

I've read somewhere that the completion is meant to be related to CEDET somehow but I couldn't make out much more (I'm working on Doom Emacs, and I seen to have CEDET installed, and can run matlab-cedet-setup, which does nothing as far as I can tell).

As to function definitions - I don't even know where to start.. I've read that ctags now supports matlab, but I don't know where (if) the actual .m files for the built-in functions reside in the install dir.

Ideally I'd love to be able to stand on a function name and be able to get the "help funcName" output in another buffer or something (this works from the shell).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am experiencing something similar. For example AC of "norm" returns:
Company: An error occurred in auto-begin
Company: backend company-matlab-shell error "Internal error, ’emacsdocomplete('nor')’ returned unexpected output, ut =

  java.lang.String[]:

    'norm'
    'norm2'
    'normalize'
    'normalizeDFT2Coefficients'
    'normalizeWords'
    'norminv'
    'normlms'
    'normpdf'
    'normplot'
    'normprod'
    'normr'
    'normrank'
    'normrnd'
    'normspec'    'northarrow'

" with args (prefix)
user-error: Cannot complete at point
Mark set

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the output is read-only in Doom Emacs. As a workaround use `inhibit-read-only`.

I did it like this:

```
(defadvice! inhibit-real-only-a (oldfun &rest r) 
 "Temporary remove read-only lines in shell buffer"
 :around#'matlab-shell-collect-command-output
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t)) (apply oldfun r)))
```

Comment: How does this work? Are we supposed to put it in out init file? If so it has not worked for me. I am using GNU emacs 27.1. Thanks

Comment: @Ajned, it works only with Doom Emacs, where you have to add it to config.el